# Survey via Lotus Notes+access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm developing an access vba application that sends Survey emails via Lotus Notes to our staff, based on different parameters. I would like these emails to include option buttons (embedded OLE objects)so our staff selects the desired options and clicks a button to send the answer back.

I can create these emails, embed the objects and send them from the 'Stationery' folder in Lotus Notes.

Since I'm a newbie to LotusScript:

What code should I insert into the button so I could receive back the selected options? Is it as simple as forwarding the original email back? I guess I could get the selected values via richtextitem, am I right?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are making the job harder for yourself by using Stationery and buttons in a rich text field.  Why not just design a standard Notes form and mail it with the store-form-in-document option?

Comment: Thanks in advance. Well I was just trying to design "something" than wouldn't require IT intervention and, for what I know, to design a notes Form requires Domino Designer something that Business does not have. My idea was to give someting to Business that would only require from them to create a stationery, indicate its name in the access vba application, and have it running. Do you have any other approach?

Comment: Domino Designer is now a free download for development and test purposes, but deployment of applications built with it onto a server does require a license.  May I ask: how were you intending to receive and process the results?  Normally, I would expect you to put a mail-in database on the Domino server and write an agent to process the results. Did you have some other plan?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, my plan is to avoid Notes server by doing the following:1) The form will result (via LotusScript in an OLE command button) on sending back to a mailbox an email that will include, in its body, the checked values. 2) My access database will scan that mailbox (in fact a folder of it) all received responses to fill the required fields of a table. So, in fact, the agent will run in the access app.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers above, I suspect that your easiest course of action will be to include a "Reply-To" header in your email with the address of the mailbox that your Access code will scan, and include instructions to your user to "Reply with History to this message, make your selections, and then click Send".

However, another way to do it would be to create two prototype documents with rich text fields in a database that your code can access.  In the first document, manually create a Notes button (not OLE) with @Command([Compose];"Reply With History") and an appropriate label.  In the second document, manually create a button with @MailSend("your application's mailbox address").  Then write code to create your survey document, read the first prototype and it's rich text item and use the AppendRTItem method to put the prototype contents into the rich text field of your new document.  Then write your code to insert your OLE survey stuff into the rich text.  Finally, read the second prototype and its rich text item and use AppendRTItem again to tack it onto the end of your survey document's rich text item.

Comment: Wow excellent! That's what I was looking for:AppendRTItem to insert objects. But I guess a prototype can only be created with Designer, something Business Unit does not have. My solution until now: I manually create the survey document as an stationery: 2 questions, 6 checkbox each and a 'Send button' (OLE). I insert in their events the necessary code in Lotus script to know what the user has selected (only 1 checkbox can be selected per question). Since I know what has been selected (uidoc.getobject...) I can send back to the mailbox a "silent" email (saveonsend=false) with some info to scan.

Comment: If you can do LotusScript code, you obviously have Domino Designer, so I don't understand why you think you can't create the prototype documents with predefined buttons for "Reply With History" and "Send".

Comment: I wouldn't in any case, contradict a 19-year Lotus Notes developer, but I can assure our Business Unit has only the usual Lotus Notes Client. But well, maybe I'm wrong, I'll check again. Many many thanks for your feedback. I really appreciate it.